# Module augmentation not working Typescript, Prisma NextAuth error, not finding User

Tags: javascript, typescript, prisma, next-auth

im using module augmentation to declare my user, this is to define the isAdmin property for the user and check if the user has admin privileges and show orders for a single user or all orders for admins. For some reason the module augmentation is not picking up the user in my auth.ts file and its saying  user is undefined saying "message": "Property 'user' does not exist on type 'PrismaClient<PrismaClientOptions, never, DefaultArgs>'.",

I was going through the lama dev food delivery tutorial on youtube and hit this roadblock

auth.ts file below

```
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter";
import { NextAuthOptions, User, getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import { prisma } from "./connect";

declare module "next-auth" {
  interface Session {
    user: User & {
      isAdmin: Boolean;
    };
  }
}
declare module "next-auth/jwt" {
  interface JWT {
    isAdmin: Boolean;
  }
}

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      // clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID as string,
      // clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET as string,
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET!,
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async session({ token, session }) {
      if (token) {
        session.user.isAdmin = token.isAdmin;
      }
      return session;
    },
    async jwt({ token }) {
      const userInDb = await prisma.user.findUnique({
        where: {
          email: token.email!,
        },
      });
      token.isAdmin = userInDb?.isAdmin!;
      return token;
    },
  },
};

export const getAuthSession = () => getServerSession(authOptions);
```

I also have my prisma schema file below FYI, this all looks fine on my end but for life of me cant pinpoint the error:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Account {
  id                String  @id @default(cuid())
  userId            String
  type              String
  provider          String
  providerAccountId String
  refresh_token     String? @db.Text
  access_token      String? @db.Text
  expires_at        Int?
  token_type        String?
  scope             String?
  id_token          String? @db.Text
  session_state     String?

  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@unique([provider, providerAccountId])
}

model Session {
  id           String   @id @default(cuid())
  sessionToken String   @unique
  userId       String
  expires      DateTime
  user         User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}

model User {
  id            String    @id @default(cuid())
  name          String?
  email         String?   @unique
  emailVerified DateTime?
  image         String?
  isAdmin       Boolean   @default(false)
  accounts      Account[]
  sessions      Session[]
  Order         Order[]
}

model VerificationToken {
  identifier String
  token      String   @unique
  expires    DateTime

  @@unique([identifier, token])
}

model Category {
  id        String    @id @default(cuid())
  createdAt DateTime  @default(now())
  title     String
  desc      String
  color     String
  img       String
  slug      String    @unique
  products  Product[]
}

model Product {
  id         String   @id @default(cuid())
  createdAt  DateTime @default(now())
  title      String
  desc       String
  img        String?
  price      Decimal
  isFeatured Boolean  @default(false)
  options    Json[]
  category   Category @relation(fields: [catSlug], references: [slug])
  catSlug    String
}

model Order {
  id        String   @id @default(cuid())
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  price     Decimal
  products  Json[]
  status    String
  intent_id String?  @unique
  user      User     @relation(fields: [userEmail], references: [email])
  userEmail String
}
```